# Significant difference in render time depending on design pattern used

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I created a WPF View as a UserControl with a DataGrid including the ability to Add/Edit/Delete records.  The View has an accompanying ViewModel that manages the contents of the DataGrid.   The ViewModel is then bound to a TabControl in the MainView’s XAML and works as expected.  The DataGrid renders over 3100 records quickly. The DataGrid is very responsive allowing me to alter the data as needed.

The MainView was then altered to render the ViewModel using a Button and a ContentControl following the pattern cited in Rachel Lim’s Blog.

The difference in performance is striking.  It takes about 15 seconds to render the data.  The DataGrid’s responsiveness is very poor.  In short, it’s not useable.

The service call in the ViewModel retrieved the records as expected.   The issue appears to be with the DataGrid.  It’s laboring to render the records.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details. Currently, your question just can't be answered as it lacks a lot of important information: provide "before" and "after" code snippets, show another relevant code. We need a [mcve] to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!  There was on subtle difference between the two views.  The data grid in the Tab Control version used a fixed Height and Width.  The Control Control version did not specify Height or Width and of course spent time determining the required size to render all 3100 rows.  Upon setting the Height and Width the Content Control version worked just fine.